# How to select different bones while in weight paint mode?

Tags: interface, weight-painting

I seem to remember being able to select different bones of a rig while in weight paint mode.

However, now when I try to do this I end up selecting a face (used for masking) instead of the bone:

[image]

How did I change this and how can I select bones while in weight paint mode?

---

Upon further investigation this face selection is used for masking, and bones can be selected with <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd>.

However, I can't figure out where this behavior came from.. I've tested it in blender 2.69 through 2.73, and in every version blender defaults to selecting bones with plain <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> and there seems to be no way to select or enable selection of faces while in weight paint mode. I couldn't find any settings regarding masking while in weight paint either.

**So the real question is**: What did I enable to allow this face selection masking feature?

Comment: Wow! I never came across this before! Could be handy once we figure it out . . .

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise Indeed, I actually quite like the face masking feature. But I'd like to know how I enabled it.. I vaguely remember reading about something like it in some release notes or something somewhere, however no amount of googling as helped me find where I read it. I even manually re-read all the release notes since 2.67 or so, but didn't see anything. A real puzzle :P

Comment: In Weight paint mode, Face masking can be turn on and off by M, vertex masking is V, if that's what you are wondering.

Comment: @LeonCheung Thanks, that's exactly it. Feel free to write it in an answer ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although the officially-suggested workflow is to select face mask by switching to Edit mode (since more powerful selection tools there), you can also quickly select faces or verts for masking In Weight Paint mode by toggling the two [image] buttons located on the headerbar, or simply press <kbd>M</kbd> or <kbd>V</kbd> to toggle them on/off.