# Custom shortcuts: Copying the "full" data path for a button

Tags: python, weight-painting, shortcut

After trying to create a shortcut for "Vertex selection mask in weight paint mode" for a while, I found much to my joy that Blender already had a shortcut for this (V, as described in [this helpful answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23330/20763)).

Comparing my setup with Blender's shortcut I found that my shortcut's operator was correct (wm.context_toggle), but the attribute I obtained from "Copy Data Path" on the vertex toggle button was incomplete. What I received was "use_paint_mask_vertex" while the correct setup (from Blender's default) is "weight_paint_object.data.use_paint_mask_vertex".

So my question is (for future reference) - How do I copy the full/correct data path for creating custom shortcuts? Also is there a better way to find out default shortcuts than searching in the User Preference panel? It did not list a shortcut for weight paint vertex mask when I searched; being able to right-click on a button element and see the default shortcut would be nice :)

(Blender version: 2.74)

Thanks for any input!